# Getting correct URL when using GET

Tags: php, html, forms

When clicking a button, I would like my URL to become this:

```
users.php?action=search&formvar1=value&formvar2=value&...
```

This is what I've tried:

```
<form id="search" action="users.php?action=search" method="get">
```

But this doesn't seem to work (it doesn't add the action=search part). Is there any way to do this? I know it works when using POST instead of GET, so why wouldn't it here?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that similarly to a POST form. Simply include the default attribute as hidden form field:

```
<form id="search" action="users.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
```

This way it will be added as parameter to the URL like all other variables.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is building the query string from scratch.

Instead, you can add an `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />`.